# Handling session data using a static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have on my hands a Windows forms application where there is a clear separation of GUI and business logic. The solution is big (40 projects, thousands of classes, about 2000 database tables). My task is to find a solution on how to reuse business logic to build a web application as a front end.

The main issue is, I think, our static Session class which is used by every other class in the solution:

```
public static class Session
{
    public static string CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public static string CurrentDatabase { get; set; }

    public static string CurrentCompanyProfile { get; set; }

    public static string CurrentLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

This class will not work in ASP.NET where it will be shared by all users and I cannot replace it since it is used a lot.

I was thinking that I need to remove all information from this class and keep just the interface. By calling the get method of an property code would somehow redirect this call to HttpContext.Current.Session where I would store a class which would contain all this info.

I'm not sure how to do this properly considering that Session resides in an assembly which will not have a reference to System.Web and considering that I must not disrupt our WinForms implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: The session would only need to hold 4 strings? Potentially, how large is the client base that will use the website?

Comment: No, this class is just an illustration. Our class is more complex than this. Client base is about few hundred clients. This is our ERP solution which is a main product which we sell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can update the Session class, you can abstract the storage of the properties in the Session class. In your current application you can create a simple in-memory storage, and in the web application you can create a web-session storage.

First define a session-value-provider, which you use in your current static Session class.

```
public interface ISessionValueProvider {
    string CurrentUser { get; set; }
    string CurrentDatabase { get; set; }
    string CurrentCompanyProfile { get; set; }
    string CurrentLanguage { get; set; }
}

public static class Session {
    private static ISessionValueProvider _sessionValueProvider;
    public static void SetSessionValueProvider(ISessionValueProvider provider) {
        _sessionValueProvider = provider;
    }

    public static string CurrentUser { 
        get { return _sessionValueProvider.CurrentUser; } 
        set { _sessionValueProvider.CurrentUser = value; } 
    }
    // Etc for the other props
}
```

Than for your current application, define a sesion value provider which uses memory to storage the values.

```
public class MemorySessionValueProvider: ISessionValueProvider {
    public string CurrentUser {get; set; }
    // Etc for the other props
}
```

To use it, create an instance and give it to the static session class. For instance, you can add this to your Main method.

```
Session.SetSessionValueProvider(new MemorySessionValueProvider());
```

Now for your web application, create a session value provider which uses the web-session.

```
public class WebSessionValueProvider: ISessionValueProvider {
    private const string CURRENTUSERKEY = "CurrentUser"; // TODO: Change this if necessary
    public string CurrentUser {
        get { return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session[CURRENTUSERKEY]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session[CURRENTUSERKEY] = value; }
    }

    // Etc for the other props
}
```

And again, give an instance of this web-session-value-provider to the static session class. For instance, in the global.asax.

```
Session.SetSessionValueProvider(new WebSessionValueProvider);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container (for example [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/)) for this. Declare an interface, for example, `IStateManager`:

```
public interface IStateManager
{
    T GetItem<T>(string key);
    SetItem<T>(string key, T value);
}
```

Then, your implementation of the `Session` class will change like the following:

```
public static class Session
{
    private static IStateManager _manager;

    private static IStateManager Manager
    {
        get
        {
            if (_manager == null)
            {
                IStateManager m = null; // Get instance using IoC container
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _manager, m, null);
            }

            return _manager;
        }
    }

    public static string CurrentUser
    {
        get { return Manager.GetItem<string>("CurrentUser"); }
        set { Manager.SetItem<string>("CurrentUser", value); }
    }

    // The rest is similar
}
```

For WinForms, the implementation will just operate on a static instance, for ASP.NET you'd have a different implementation that maintains data in the session. The benefit is that you'll just have different *installers* for different environments and your code doesn't need to know about them at all (therefore, the logic won't be dependent on either WinForms or ASP.NET).

Also, this approach is testable (it's very easy to mock the `IStateManager` using [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/), for example).

Comment: Yes, that would be better but I think the OP wants minimal (zero) change in the existing code.

Comment: Zero change in existing code is a must unfortunately, your're right.

Comment: Thanks. I had to refresh my knowledge of CompareExchange() method.