# How to create a class for session in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Im new to MVC.. How to create a class for session like this ..
abstract the storage of the properties in the Session class.. Please help me out in right way.. Thanks alot in advance

```
public interface Isession {
    string CurrentUserName();
    string CurrentUserPassword();
    string CurrentUserProfile();
    string CurrentUserLanguage();
    void ClearAllSession();
}

public class Session:Isession {
    Public static string CurrentUserName{
        get ....?
        set...?
    }
    Public static string CurrentUserPassword{
        get ....?
        set...?
    }
    Public static string CurrentUserProfile{
        get ....?
        set...?
    }
    Public static string CurrentUserLanguage{
        get ....?
        set...?
    }
    Public Static Void ClearAllSession{
    ??
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I gotta good example for the MVC : Session Variables...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240227/MVC-Test-Driven-Developement-Session-Variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for a single property.

```
public class Session : ISession {
    private const string CURRENTUSERKEY = "CurrentUser";
    public static string CurrentUser {
        get { return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session[CURRENTUSERKEY]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session[CURRENTUSERKEY] = value; }
    }

    public static void ClearAllSession() {
        CurrentUser = null; // And the other props
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012731/261050).

Comment: Here I gotta good example for the MVC : Session Variables...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240227/MVC-Test-Driven-Developement-Session-Variables

Comment: @naveenkumar Thanks! But you might want to add it as a comment to the question :-)

Comment: If I have a 10 session props means I have to mention all in it??    ClearAllSession() {
        CurrentUser = null; // And the other props
    }

Comment: Yep, you have to mention all.